# SQL: Select time period COUNT() of employees

Tags: sql, date, select, time, count

Good day,

The "SELECT" below shows the number of employees and their arrival and departure times.

In this data, I need to find out the total number of employees (COUNT) at each time (I do not need to deal with seconds). How many people worked at the same time in a given period of time.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    linka.xLinka
    , linka.xDoklad
    , zam.xPracovnik
    , FORMAT(zam.xCasOd, 'HH:mm') as cas_od
    , FORMAT(zam.xCasDo, 'HH:mm') as cas_do
FROM [K2CA_CA].[dbo].[_OV_Data01] as linka
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._OV_Data03 as zam ON zam.xLinka = linka.xLinka and zam.xDoklad = linka.xDoklad
WHERE linka.xRok = 2021
    --AND linka.xDen  >= '2021-10-20' and linka.xDen <= '2021-10-26'
    AND (zam.xPozice like '%Bale%' or zam.xPozice like '%Plnič%')
```

Result:

```
Line                   Document       Employee            Arrival   Departure
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Vaněček Karel       |   22:00 06:00
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Levá Pavlína        |   23:30 06:00
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Škorňová Alena      |   01:30 06:00
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Trofimov Jurii      |   01:30 06:00
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Besahina Olena      |   01:30 06:00
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Havel Zdeněk        |   01:30 06:00
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Schmiedlová Ilona   |   01:30 06:00
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   Kulenová Jinřiška   |   01:30 06:00
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result, which i need earn:

```
Line                   Document       COUNT(*)            Arrival   Departure
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   1               |   22:00 23:30 (22 - 23:30) work only one employee)
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   2               |   23:30 01:30 (23:30 - 1:30 works two employees - first arived at 22:00, second at 23:30))
 | Balíčky, výroba nových NV   |   VL/2021/4072   |   8               |   01:30 06:00 (8 employes work here from 1:30 to 06:00)
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to get the result? Or how do I get the timeline definition? For example, that employee 1 was alone from  and to and another employee was alone from and to and etc. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more likely to be answered if you

- specify your db vendor (instead of unnecessary `select` tag)
- provide minimalistic example (no underlying tables or unrelated where conditions)
- provide db fiddle
- bonus: anonymize sensitive data

To answer itself:

1. You should first improve representation of times since string "HH:mm" format does not give a clue how to sort 01:30 after 23:30. Probably you want datetime type truncated or rounded to minutes. Let's name it `cas_od`, `cas_do` like in your code snippet.
2. Then define ordered set of all ranges:

```sql
with original as (
  ... your select with cas_od, cas_do and other preprocessed data
), times(cas_od,cas_do) as (
  select cas, lag(cas) over (order by cas) 
  from (
    select distinct cas_od as cas from original
    union
    select distinct cas_do as cas from original
  )
)
```

3. Then count number of working employes for each range (there might be boundary errors but I hope you get the idea):

```sql
select t.cas_od, t.cas_do
     , (select count(*)
        from original o
        where o.cas_od<=t.cas_od and o.cas_do>=t.cas_do
       )
from times t
```

Comment: I really thank you for help, period of times looks correctly, but one problem Is with range od day. Because if one employee start at 22:00 And work to next day so his result Is with null.

Comment: And second problem Is with count. Now i have four result which is correctly but count look me value with 2,4,4,4 but correctly Is 1, 2, 8, 7. Because i have eight people. First work in period 22:00-00:30 alone, two work in period 0:30-1:30, eight work in 1:30-5:00 And 7 work in 5:00-6:00 . All people have same end time.

Comment: Please improve question in four points stated in the beginning of my answer. It is otherwise very hard to help you without seeing data snippet and what you are trying with it. Create db fiddle and let's discuss over it.

Comment: I really apologize for my inaccurate questions but i found problem. Your select work correctly. Problem was in my select but can you tell me if i select only time period how can i added to time period information about machine. 

Exactly this line from my select "linka.xLinka, linka.xDoklad"

Comment: If your `line` and `document` columns are constants as in your example you can safely put them into `select 'Balíčky', ... from times` query. Otherwise it is necessary to describe in what context they vary. For instance, is the series of time points to be processed within group of records of same `line` and `document`? Minimal reproducible example would give an answer, I am sorry I have no chance to guess it from provided example.